# Is it possible to use Hadoop's MapReduce to write key-value pairs to different files based on predetermined key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to separate the key/value pairs resulting from this hadoop job into different files according to the predetermined key values in different files.

For example, in the Startup (X) file there are key-values. If there are matches according to the keys in file A, I want to write them to a file, and if there are matches in file B, I want to write them to a different file. The number of files is unknown (A,B,C,...). How can I code this mapreduce programming model?

| X | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abby,4 | Abby | Adriana |
| Adriana,2 | Anna | Blake |
| Anna,2 | Christina | Carolina |
| Blake,1 |  |  |
| Carolina,1 |  |  |
| Christina,1 |  |  |

| A_new | B_new |
| --- | --- |
| Abby,4 | Adriana,2 |
| Anna,2 | Blake,1 |
| Christina,1 | Carolina,1 |

Comment: You could use Spark to filter data by starting characters, then write separate files... Why do you need mapreduce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) to write content to different files.

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "fileA", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "fileB", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
```